# 1-year-old questions removed by Roomba: what happened if they are re-asked?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, statistics, auto-delete

When a question is one-year-old, has received 0 upvote, 0 answer, fewer than 2 comments and not many visitors, it gets automatically removed.

Has anyone looked at what happened if such questions are re-asked? E.g., what percentage of then would they get an answer or some upvotes?

Comment: I doubt many of them even get re-asked after an entire year has passed. Determining how well those that *did* get re-asked were received would require a lot of manual work, because the system won't allow them to just copy paste and thus the body and title will be different. There's no good way to programmatically determine "this is a re-post of a previously deleted question." The closest thing you could get is "this person asked a question shortly after having one auto-deleted." Unless you were looking for stats on how many get edited and/or undeleted and then receive answers afterwards.

Comment: @animuson Sure I was thinking perhaps some admin or mod did some experiment, before deciding to trash user content (as a way to gauge whether roomba truly discards low quality content). Seems like a basic test to me.

Comment: Just asked a related question: [What percentage of questions which are deleted by the Roomba later get undeleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357875/what-percentage-of-questions-which-are-deleted-by-the-roomba-later-get-undeleted)